# real analysis - interior points of a set

Tags: real-analysis

I need help constructing an if-and-only-if proof for the following:

Let $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Define $E^o$ to be the interior points of $E$. Then $E^o$ is compact if and only if $E^o = ∅$.

I have experience proving that $E$ is open if $E^o = E$, and that $E$ is closed if $\bar E = E$, but I've never seen a proof that's presented like this.

Answer (score 4):

Compact sets are closed. If the open set $E^{0}$ is compact then it is open and closed. Since $\mathbb R$ is connected the only sets that are both open and closed are the empty set and $\mathbb R$. Conclusion?

Proof without using connectedness: any open set in $\mathbb R$ is of the form $\cup_n (a_n,b_n)$ where the intervals are disjoint. If we write $E^{0}$ in this form and if we know that it is compact then $E^{0}=\cup_{n=1}^{N} (a_n,b_n)$ for some $N$. But then $E^{0}$ is the union of $(a_n,b_n),2\leq n \leq N$ and the intervals $(a_1+\frac 1 k, b_1-\frac 1 k)$ , so we get an open  cover which has no finite subcover.

Third proof: if $E^{0}$ is compact and nonempty then it has smallest element, say $x$. Since the set is open there exists $r>0$ such that $(x-r,x+r) \subset E^{0}$. But then $x-\frac r 2 \in E^{0}$ and this element is smaller than $x$, which is  contradiction.

Comment: In my class, we haven't learned about connected spaces yet. Do you know how to prove this without using the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is connected? Thank you for answering.

Comment: @YeetYah See if my second proof is accessible.

Comment: I am new to real analysis. I'm sorry, but some of your notation is a little confusing for me to follow. So, any open set is a union of what exactly?  Why is $E^o$ the union of $(a_n, b_n), 2 \leq n \leq N$?

Comment: @YeetYah Any open set can be written as the union of sequence of disjoint open intervals.  For each point in the open set there is a largest open interval around that point which is contained in the open set. You can verify that the collection of all these maximal intervals has the properties we need.

Comment: This is making much more sense now, thanks. Is there a proof we can write using sequences? Perhaps a proof of contradiction?

Comment: @YeetYah OK, I have added  a third proof.

Comment: @YeetYah. A non-empty open $S\subset \Bbb R$ is equal to $\cup \Bbb J$ where $\Bbb J$ is a pairwise-disjoint family of non-empty convex open sets. (Note that open half-lines, and $\Bbb R$ itself, are convex open sets, as are bounded open intervals.).... For each $I\in \Bbb J$ let $f(I)\in I\cap \Bbb Q.$ Then$ f:\Bbb J\to \Bbb Q$ is injective (because $\Bbb J$ is a pairwise -disjoint family) and $\Bbb Q$ is countable, so $\Bbb J$ is countable. (Countable means "finite or countably infinite".)

Comment: Thank you so much!